# Sharepoint Online link to stylesheet is counted as a page control in master page. Why?

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, master-page

If I add a simple link to a stylesheet to a master page I get the

> "you have more than 200 controls" error.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
```

Why would a link like that be counted as a control and is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a separate CSS style sheet independent of your master page without modifying it by setting `Alternate CSS URL` for a specific CSS file or URL as the following:

- Open your site.
- Go to Site Setting > Look and Feel > Master Page.
- At Alternate CSS URL > Select Specify CSS file > Check `Reset all subsites to inherit this alternate CSS URL` in case you need to apply the CSS on all subsite.

[image]

> **Note**: the Master Page option is only available in the
>   Publishing site or team site with Publishing feature enabled.

Comment: I don't think that's a good practice but I suppose it. might work - the bigger question is really about why a link to a stylesheet is counted as a control.

Comment: what do you mean it's not good practice? what's the good practice from your opinion ?! regarding the error try to add it like this <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

Comment: I just mean this is not an "alternate" stylesheet - that's already been added to a custom master page. This is an additional stylesheet for font awesome and adding the text/css reference still results in an error. Again, I'd like to understand why a link like this is counted as a control because Msft support doesn't seem to know.